# TypedQuery result incompatible using Hibernate and PlayFramework

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework-2.0

i'm having this problem when calling this simple method that allows me to get a user by it's Username:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String username;


    @Constraints.Required
    public String password;


    public boolean isAdmin;

    public static User findById(Long id) {
        return JPA.em().find(User.class, id);
    }

    public void update(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
        JPA.em().merge(this);
    }

    public void save() {
        JPA.em().persist(this);
    }

    public void delete() {
        JPA.em().remove(this);
    }


    public static User findByUsername(String username) {
        Query query = JPA.em().createQuery("select u from User u where username = :username", User.class);
        query.setParameter("username", username);
        return (User) query.getSingleResult();
    }

}
```

The error arrives at the query creation and it's:

```
[IllegalArgumentException: Type specified for TypedQuery [models.User] is incompatible with query return type [interface java.util.Map]]
```

I'm using Hibernate and PlayFramework, does anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: The problem was that the entity defined in Java was incoherent with the database. So when play tried to merge the results of the query with the Entity it failed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with Play’s development mode. You’ll find that your code works if you use it with the `start` command rather than the `run` command.

I assume that this has something to do with the class reloading. The (version of the) class that you’re using doesn’t exist when Hibernate is initiated. When Hibernate can’t find the type that is returned by the query, it falls back to `Map`. When it then compares it to your class argument, it sees that there is something wrong and complains.

I have found no way around this problem, other than to not use typed queries, which is no fun at all :-(

Comment: Hey, sorry but the problem was that the entity defined in Java was incoherent with the database.

Comment: This answer is valid. I have observed that restarting the server resolves the issue.

Answer (score -2):

Your select is nonsense. You cannot do `select u from User u`. You either have to specify one or more columns like

```
select u.password from User u where u.username = :username
```

- which would you return a single String -

or you fetch the complete record

```
from User u where u.username = :username
```

which returns an instance of User (the `select` keyword is not necessary here).

Comment: Yes, my query was not right but that is because i have changed it while trying to solve my problem. I have tried your query and I get the same error.